# Sequelize - Unknown column in 'order clause' when sorting by included model

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have the following Sequelize query:

```
const sites = await Site.findAndCountAll({
        order: [[{model: Account, as: 'account'}, 'name', 'DESC']];
        limit: limits.limit,
        offset: limits.offset,
        where,
        include: [
            {
                model: Account,
                as: 'account',
                attributes: ['account_id', 'name', 'customer_id'],
                paranoid: false,
                required: true,
                include: [
                    {
                        model: Customer,
                        attributes: ['customer_id', 'name'],
                        paranoid: false,
                        required: true,
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                model: Version,
                as: 'versions',
                limit: 1,
                order: [['version_id', 'desc']],
                attributes: ['status', 'config', 'user_id', 'updated_at', 'version_id', 'updated_by', 'is_abtest_parent', 'is_prod'],
                include: [
                    {
                        model: User,
                        as: 'updatedByUser',
                        attributes: ['email'],
                        paranoid: false,
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                model: SiteService,
                as: 'services',
                where: siteServiceFilter,
                required: Object.keys(siteServiceFilter).length > 0,
            },
        ],
        distinct: true,
    });
```

As you see, I'm trying to order the sites by the associated `Account` model. The query works fine without the ordering. Here are the associations between these two models:

```
Site.belongsTo(models.Account, {
    foreignKey: 'account_id',
    as: 'account'
});
```

```
Account.hasMany(models.Site, {
    foreignKey: 'account_id',
    as: 'sites',
});
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
code: 'ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR',
errno: 1054,
sqlState: '42S22',
sqlMessage: "Unknown column 'account.name' in 'order clause'",
```

Now interestingly, I don't have this issue if I omit the included `SiteService` subquery. With that commented out, the sorting by account name works as expected. So any idea how and why the included `SiteService` model could be interfering with the ordering by Account name? I'll also provide the associations with `SiteService`:

```
Site.hasMany(models.SiteService, {
    foreignKey: 'site_id',
    as: 'services',
});
```

```
SiteService.belongsTo(models.Site, {
    foreignKey: 'site_id',
    as: 'site',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've worked around the issue by simply using a literal query. So, instead of this:

```
order: [[{model: Account, as: 'account'}, 'name', 'DESC']];
```

I now have:

```
order = [[Sequelize.literal('`account.name`'), 'DESC']];
```

I still don't understand why the original approach is problematic, as it seems to follow what's described in the Sequelize docs. For many of the issues I've had with Sequelize, the solution seems to be simply not using their provided syntax and instead running a raw SQL query.